# Обработчики событий OnClose and OnShow

Tags: delphi

Как с помощью обработчиков событий `OnShow` и `OnClose`  вывести размеры и положение формы на экране, которое было при выходе, выдавать в заголовке окна. Как это реализовать? Помогите написать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тут есть два варианта: воспользоваться системным реестром Windows или использовать Ini-файлы. Я обычно пользуюсь вторым. Сперва в раздел Uses необходимо подключить модуль IniFiles. Затем пишем код на событие OnCreate для формы:

```
procedure TINIFilesForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
Var
  Ini: TIniFile; // Объект Ini-файл
begin
  Ini:=TIniFile.Create(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName)+'my.ini'); // Создаю файл
// подгоняю положение окна
  IniFilesForm.Left:=Ini.ReadInteger('Position', 'L', 329); 
  IniFilesForm.Top:=Ini.ReadInteger('Position', 'T', 261);
// подгоняю размеры окна
  IniFilesForm.Width:=Ini.ReadInteger('Size', 'W', 384);
  IniFilesForm.Height:=Ini.ReadInteger('Size', 'H', 312);
// устанавливаю заголовок окна
  IniFilesForm.Caption:=Ini.ReadString('Param', 'C', 'Программа');
// устанавливаю параметр флажка
  CheckBox.Checked:=Ini.ReadBool('Param', 'CB', False);
  Ini.Free; // Уничтожаю созданный объект
end;
```

Теперь пишем код на событие OnDestroy:

```
procedure TINIFilesForm.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
Var
  Ini: TIniFile;
begin
  Ini:=TIniFile.Create(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName)+'my.ini');
// сохраняю положение окна
  Ini.WriteInteger('Position', 'L', Left);
  Ini.WriteInteger('Position', 'T', Top);
// сохраняю размеры окна
  Ini.WriteInteger('Size', 'W', Width);
  Ini.WriteInteger('Size', 'H', Height);
// // сохраняю заголовок окна
  Ini.WriteString('Param', 'C', IniFilesForm.Caption);
// сохраняю параметр флажка
  Ini.WriteBool('Param', 'CB', CheckBox.Checked);
  Ini.Free;
end;
```

Comment: а почему onclose  u  OnShow  не испупользуются? или то, что вы написали выше, это тоже самое? Просто я только учу делфи и не совсем понимаю....

Comment: Напиши код в OnShow-OnClose будет одинаково. Просто в приведенном варианте параметры считываются при создание формы (а не при показе) и записываются при уничтожении в памяти (а не при закрытии). Кстати, при записи я еще проверяю свойство WindowState. Если форма Minimized (свернута) - то размеры и положение не записываю. Если Maximized - записываю данное состояние.

Comment: Ясно, спасибо)) я так и предпоположил))

Comment: Кстати, да, совсем забыл, Вячеслав Кириченко прав: свойство WindowState нужно, и, даже, необходимо проверять, когда происходит запись данных в файл, т. к. могут возникнуть проблемы с загрузкой программы. Если свойство WindowState=wsNormal - записываем размеры, а если WindowState=wsMaximized - записываем, например, логическое значение, означающее, что форма растянута на весь экран.

Answer (score 0):

Ещё проще записать всё в простой текстовый файл в директории самой программы, и не обязательно использовать INI, так как параметров не так уж и много и они не изменяются..., но для хорошего тона INI, конечно лучше, а вот в реестр, так считаю, складывать мусор не стоит:

```
        var Prop:textfile;
        AssignFile(Prop,extractfilepath(paramstr(0)));
        rewrite(prop);
        writeln(Prop, inttostr(self.width));
        ....
        write(Prop, ....)
        closefile(prop);
```

и, конечно, в той же последовательности считывать